# Flutter - How to access child data on parent event or action

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a longer input form where the user can add a number of identical subforms.

For e.g. think about a form where parents can enter their data (parentform) and afterwards add their childs. Since i don't know how many childs a user has they can dynamically add more child forms using a button.

For each child the requested data is identical so e.g. name, birthday, gender, in reality its about 10 fields. So i created a separate widget (childform).

If the user now saves the outer form i need to gather all information from the childforms. I now i can do this by creating all TextControllers inside the parentform, save them in a list and insert them when creating the childforms, like so:

```
void addTextField() {
  int index = _childNameControllers.length;
  _childNameControllers.add( TextEditingController());

  _childforms.add(
    RemovableEntityField(
      nameController: _childNameControllers[index]
    )
  );
}
```

And then on save something like

```
void onSave() {
  List<Childs> _childs = [];
  _childNameControllers.forEach((controller) {
    if (controller.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      _childs.add(Child(name: name));
    }
  });
  // do something with the data
}
```

But as i said i have about 10 Fields per childform and i would have to create 10 controllers for each form and would need 10 parameters in the  childform just to read this information.
**Is there an easier way to do this ?**

PS: i know i could make the child state public but i don't really want to do this either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are supposed to add variable updater in the child and push the value up to the parent.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/4b4cff94bf6631bf6326c9239c10b286b4fdb08c/dev/benchmarks/test_apps/stocks

The flutter stock application has an example.

In the child you need this.

```
class StockSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const StockSettings(this.configuration, this.updater);

  final StockConfiguration configuration;
  final ValueChanged<StockConfiguration> updater;

  @override
  StockSettingsState createState() => StockSettingsState();
}

class StockSettingsState extends State<StockSettings> {
void _handleBackupChanged(bool value) {
    sendUpdates(widget.configuration.copyWith(backupMode: value ? BackupMode.enabled : BackupMode.disabled));
}

void sendUpdates(StockConfiguration value) {
    if (widget.updater != null)
      widget.updater(value);
}
```

In the parent, you pass down configuartion updator which is just a wrapper around set state

```
class StocksAppState extends State<StocksApp> {
  StockData stocks;

  StockConfiguration _configuration = StockConfiguration(
    stockMode: StockMode.optimistic,
    backupMode: BackupMode.enabled,
    debugShowGrid: false,
    debugShowSizes: false,
    debugShowBaselines: false,
    debugShowLayers: false,
    debugShowPointers: false,
    debugShowRainbow: false,
    showPerformanceOverlay: false,
    showSemanticsDebugger: false
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stocks = StockData();
  }

  void configurationUpdater(StockConfiguration value) {
    setState(() {
      _configuration = value;
    });
}

routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
         '/':         (BuildContext context) => StockHome(stocks, _configuration, configurationUpdater),
         '/settings': (BuildContext context) => StockSettings(_configuration, configurationUpdater)
},
```

Comment: Since the "save" button is on the parent form i would then have to save all changes every time the user makes any input (change listeners on all text fields, maybe with delay) or am i wrong here ?

Comment: The whole point of Flutter is to make rebuilding cheap. I would not worry about performance unless you are doing something fundamentally expensive